# Get product of age gap on the path

Tags: gremlin

Given a graph like:

```
g.V().drop()

g.addV('Person').property(id, 'P1').property('age', 20)
g.addV('Person').property(id, 'P2').property('age', 70)
g.addV('Person').property(id, 'P3').property('age', 32)
g.addV('Person').property(id, 'P4').property('age', 50)
g.addV('Person').property(id, 'P5').property('age', 63)

g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P1')).to(V('P2'))
g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P2')).to(V('P3'))
g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P3')).to(V('P4'))
g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P4')).to(V('P5'))
g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P2')).to(V('P5'))
g.addE('KNOWS').from(V('P3')).to(V('P5'))
```

I want to know all the paths between `P1` and `P5` induced by `KNOWS` edge, then calculate the product of age gap on the path.

By now, I can only get the path:

```
gremlin> g.V('P1').
......1>   repeat(both('KNOWS').simplePath()).
......2>   until(hasId('P5')).path()
==>[v[P1],v[P2],v[P5]]
==>[v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P5]]
==>[v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P4],v[P5]]

gremlin> g.V('P1').
......1>   repeat(both('KNOWS').simplePath()).
......2>   until(hasId('P5')).path().by("age")
==>[20,70,63]
==>[20,70,32,63]
==>[20,70,32,50,63]
```

To make the meaning of `product of age gap` clear, take the first path `[20,70,63]` for example: the age gap is `[70-20, 63-70]`, which is  `[50, -7]`, age gap need to be positive, so product is `50 * 7 = 350`.

The expected output is:

```
==>[path: [v[P1],v[P2],v[P5]], product: 350]
==>[path: [v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P5]], product: 58900]
==>[path: [v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P4],v[P5]], product: 444600]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be prepared for some serious Gremlin golf.

```
g.V('P1').
  repeat(both('KNOWS').simplePath()).
    until(hasId('P5')).
  project('path','product').
    by(path()).
    by(path().
         by('age').
       repeat(filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).  /* for each pair of ages ...     */
              sack(assign).
                by(limit(local, 1)).
              skip(local, 1).
              sack(minus).                     /* ... calculate the difference  */
                by(limit(local, 1))).
         emit().
       sack().fold().                          /* fold gaps into a list and ... */
       sack(assign).
         by(limit(local, 1)).
       skip(local, 1).
       until(__.not(unfold())).
         repeat(sack(mult).                    /* ... calculate the product     */
                  by(limit(local, 1)).
                  skip(local, 1)).
       choose(sack().is(lt(0)),                /* make sure gaps are positive   */
                sack(mult).by(constant(-1))).
       sack())
```

Looks very complicated, but there are mainly two simple things happening. After getting a list of ages (`path().by('age')`), the first `repeat()` collects the gaps between ages. The gaps are folded into a new list and passed to the second `repeat()`, which then calculates the products.

**On your sample graph:**

```
gremlin> g.V('P1').
......1>   repeat(both('KNOWS').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasId('P5')).
......3>   project('path','product').
......4>     by(path()).
......5>     by(path().
......6>          by('age').
......7>        repeat(filter(count(local).is(gt(1))).
......8>               sack(assign).
......9>                 by(limit(local, 1)).
.....10>               skip(local, 1).
.....11>               sack(minus).
.....12>                 by(limit(local, 1))).
.....13>          emit().
.....14>        sack().fold().
.....15>        sack(assign).
.....16>          by(limit(local, 1)).
.....17>        skip(local, 1).
.....18>        until(__.not(unfold())).
.....19>          repeat(sack(mult).
.....20>                   by(limit(local, 1)).
.....21>                   skip(local, 1)).
.....22>        choose(sack().is(lt(0)),
.....23>                 sack(mult).by(constant(-1))).
.....24>        sack())
==>[path:[v[P1],v[P2],v[P5]],product:350]
==>[path:[v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P5]],product:58900]
==>[path:[v[P1],v[P2],v[P3],v[P4],v[P5]],product:444600]
```

Comment: nicely done. always neat to see what gremlin can do when pushed. i'd just make a practical point - unless you explicitly need the "age range" for the further processing of the traversal, the other approach would be to simply post process the result and do the "age range" calculation in the application.

Comment: perfect! as a matter of fact, i'm trying to write gremlin dsl for IC14 in ldbc-snb http://ldbc.github.io/ldbc_snb_docs/ldbc-snb-specification.pdf , but even with your excellent help, i can't figure it out. as now, I face the problem of calculate the match pattern between two consecutive vertices inside a list.